# Adding web reference dynamics crm

Tags: asp.net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

Hi I am trying to follow this article but am stuck on importing one of the web references.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb955359.aspx

This bit:

To add the CrmService Web service reference

In the Solution Explorer window, right-click your project name and choose Add Web Reference.
In the Add Web Reference wizard, type the URL for the CrmService Web service in the URL box, using the name and port number for your Microsoft Dynamics CRM server, and then click Go. For example:
http:///mscrmservices/2007/CrmServiceWsdl.aspx

When I go to this address I can see the wsdl definition but the Add reference box never activates.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

From "Programming Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0" by Steger, Snyder, Bosak, O'Brien and Richardson:

1. [...]
2. Right-click the project and then click Add Service Reference.
3. Click the Advanced button in the Add Service Reference box.
4. In the Service Reference Settings box, click Add Web Reference.
5. In the Add Web Reference dialog box, add the CrmService reference:

   1. In the URL box, type `http://<crmserver>/mscrmservices/2007/crmservice.asmx` and then click Go.
   2. In the Web reference name box, type `CrmSdk`. (Note that if you are using C#, this is case sensitive.)
   3. Click Add Reference.

Comment: I have the same problem, but for me it always redirects to: /mscrmservices/2007/CrmServiceWsdl.aspx

Any idea?